# rm doesn't remove files even though the path is correct

Tags: git-bash

I have a bash script in my tomcat bin folder. When I run the script it is supposed to delete the logs. For some reason when I run the command through the script it says the files don't exist. If I run the same command manually it works just fine.

```
TOMCAT=${PWD%/*}
rm $TOMCAT/logs/*
```

when I run the script I get this: 
rm: cannot remove '/home/cwall/Desktop/osp/tomcat/logs/*': No such file or directory

but when I run this: 
`cwall:~/Desktop/osp/tomcat/bin> rm /home/cwall/Desktop/osp/tomcat/logs/*`

it works, and I can't figure out why.

(just as a note the script does a lot more than this. This is the only relevant code.)

(edit) 
I have found a solution to this problem. I would not be able to give a sufficient answer without explaining my entire script. This question should probably be removed, but I will leave it up for now.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that your working directory is `/osp/` then try

`TOMCAT=$PWD
 rm $TOMCAT/logs/*`